# Trying to implement Redigo ScanStruct but limited examples to follow

Tags: go, redis

I have a code:

```
values, err := redis.Values(c.Do("hgetall", value))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("HGETALL", err)
}

/*
type UD struct {
    created_at  string
    B           time.Time
    ended_at    string
    data        string
    status      string
}
*/
if err := redis.ScanStruct(values, &UD); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

The error I got is

> redigo.ScanStruct: cannot assign field B: cannot convert from Redis
>   bulk string to time.Time

How do I resolve this? Any examples of ScanStruct in detail for a variety of field types for Struct for reference?

Comment: Your other fields are unexported, meaning they are not being scanned into. (That may not solve your issue, but it's worth mentioning).

Comment: What happens if you change the `B` field type to a string, or a "Redis bulk string" type, whatever that is?

Comment: my struct field is time.Time, why would I want to change to string?

Comment: There are many possible ways to format a time.   Scan to a string and then decode with the format used by your application. Alternatively, write your own ScanStruct. It's just a helper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `ScanStruct` is quite clear:

> Integer, float, boolean, string and []byte fields are supported.

Other field types are not supported `time.Time` included.

To resolve this, I'd go and make my own version of ScanStruct that can deal with the conversion between Redis' and whatever types I need to throw at it.

Comment: Hi Itamar!
Thank you for the answer. Can yo share you own solution. It was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an ignore tag to make time field avoid being marshaled.

```golang
type UD struct {
    created_at  string
    B           time.Time `redis:"-"`
    ended_at    string
    data        string
    status      string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
Behind the scenes the `redis.ScanStruct()` function uses Go's `strconv` package to convert the values returned from Redis in to the appropriate Go type for the struct field — similar in principle to what we did in the previous example. By default this supports
`integer, float, boolean, string and []byte` fields.

If you need to automatically scan into a custom type, you can do so by implemeting the [`redis.Scanner()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Scanner) interface on your custom type.

PS: For more information please read this:
****[Link](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Scanner)**** and This: **[**Redis.Scanner()**](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Scanner)**